# Dealing with href when selecting multiple options

Tags: javascript, html, href, multiple-select

I am trying to give the users the option to select multiple years in my webpage, so I used the checkbox type. Currently, I am struggling at redirecting pages when the user select multiple years.

In HTML

```
<h4> Brands </h4>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="brands" name = "Nike">Nike</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="brands" name = "Adidas">Adidas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="brands" name = "Vans">Vans</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<h4> Years </h4>
<div class="mutliSelect">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="2010" />2010</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="2011" />2011</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="2012" />2012</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="2013" />2013</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="2014" />2014</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="2015" />2015</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Previously I am able to select one year with dropdown menu

```
<li><a href="{% url 'data:getdata' brands '2014' %}" class="year">2015</a></li>
```

Now, I want to redirect to a link after the user select a brand and multiple years, such as:

data/Nike/(store multiple years somehow)

Comment: Do you want to make a redirect when the checkbox is clicked or change the value of your href when the checkbox is clicked ? Be more clear/precise please.

Comment: @FDavidov not in Englis, I am trying to redirect to a link like data/Nike/[2010,2011] I am not sure if array is the right format

Comment: @Ersian I want to make a redirect when the checkbox is clicked, but it redirects after the user finish selecting multiple years

Comment: So, simply put, you want to build a URL with data that includes an array, right? If so, you may pass a JSON-like string containing a collection/array. It will then be the job of the receiver to interpret it and extract the list of values (years).

Comment: I guess my question is how to build an URL with an array containing all the years? @FDavidov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the URL you want to redirect looks like:

```
 http://www.example.com?data=...
```

and you want to send as data: 2010,2011,2013. You can send it as:

```
 http://www.example.com?data='{"List":[2010,2011,2013]}'
```

and at the receiver handle the received string as a stringifyed JSON.

Comment: what is the regrex in url for json array?

Comment: regrex??? I don't know what are you using at your server side, but today's products (e.g. JAVA, DBMSs, etc.) include full support for JSON manipulations. You don't need to build any parser at all.

Comment: By the way, you are encouraged to up-vote my answer (click on the upright triangle above).

Answer (score 0):

To redirect when it's clicked you can do that:

add `onclick='redirect(this);'` on your `<input>` list

and then create a function who will redirect

```
function redirect(e) {
    window.location.href = "data/Nike/" + e.checked
}
```

But in your example you can't handle the brand...